# Reshape vector with a step and window size

Tags: matlab, reshape

I have a vector, for example

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

I want to "reshape" it to matrix with `windowsize=4` and `stepsize=2`, such that the resulting matrix is

```
b = [ 1   3   5;   
      2   4   6;   
      3   5   7;   
      4   6   8 ]
```

Comment: Can you please further elaborate, what do you mean with "windowsize" and "stepsize"? Also, this is no reshaping, since matrix values seem to be present multiple times in the result `b`!?

Comment: 'window size' represent the number of elements in a column in output matrix 'b'. Here first 4 elements fill the first column in 'b', after the step size interval(here 2) next 4 elements from A fill second column in 'b', again after step size interval next 4 elements from A fill third column in 'b' and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up an indexing matrix, then just index into `A`...

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];

windowsize = 4;
stepsize = 2;

% Implicit expansion to create a matrix of indices
idx = bsxfun( @plus, (1:windowsize).',  0:stepsize:(numel(A)-windowsize) );

b = A(idx);
```

Note; in this case `idx` and `b` are the same, but you need the final indexing step assuming `A` isn't just consecutive integers in your real example.

Comment: Using the same approach, but using "implicit expansion" instead of `bsxfun` you could use this code: `idx = (1:s:(numel(A)-s))+(0:w-1).'`.

Comment: @obchardon Yes, after MATLAB R2016b these are equivalent... and of course you've made that look a lot more compact than using `bsxfun` primarily because you shortened the variable names ;)

Comment: I got another solution for this problem by using buffer function: idx = buffer(1:8,windowsize,stepsize,'nodelay');